# SSIS. Inserting data from MS ACCESS into SQL Server 2014 Azure. Extremely Slow

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure, ssis, sql-server-2014

I am new to SSIS. As part of my package I follow these steps

1. Create table
2. Open DataFlow task
3. Connect to Access Database
4. Insert data into SQL Server Table that was created in step 1

I have just run the step and have found that the process is taking forever. I am only bringing in 3 columns with a total row count of 255,000

```
Column A = INT
Column B = NVARCHAR (255)
Column C = NVARCHAR (255)
```

Yes, I have been lazy with the data conversion however, with such a small number of records, I didn't think that performance would be an issue at all.

After 10 minutes, only 3% of the data has been inserted. I re check the number of records in the tableafter about 10 seconds and the count only goes up by about 400 records.

I have other packages that import data from text files (much bigger) and they run in seconds, so I have a feeling that this could a MS ACCESS issue.

If this is the case, are you aware if I could use SSIS to trigger a MS ACESS job that could in turn export the file as CSV or text so that my SSIS package could pick it up? I dont want to manually open up MS ACESS and run the job as I am trying to get to as much of an automated solution as possible

Thanks in advance

Comment: Connect to Azure DB and run below query and update your question

Comment: `select 
session_id,
start_time,
command,
db_name(ec.database_id) as dbname,
blocking_session_id,
wait_type,
last_wait_type,
wait_time,
cpu_time,
logical_reads,
reads,
writes,
((database_transaction_log_bytes_used +database_transaction_log_bytes_reserved)/1024)/1024 as logusageMB,
txt.text,
pln.query_plan
 from sys.dm_exec_requests ec
 cross apply
 sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec.sql_handle) txt
 cross apply
 sys.dm_exec_query_plan(ec.plan_handle) pln
 join
 sys.dm_tran_database_transactions trn
 on trn.transaction_id=ec.transaction_id`

Comment: Sorry, but I dont have permission to run this query

Comment: Msg 300, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
VIEW SERVER STATE permission was denied on object 'server', database 'master'.
Msg 297, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The user does not have permission to perform this action.

Comment: try to run on database which your query runs,not master

Comment: I have tried but I do not have permissions for sys.dm_tran_database_transactions. Perhaps I can ask the database administrator to run it for me (not hopeful!)

Answer (score 1):

WOW! Figured it out...

Step 1: Went to my source connection and changed the data access mode from 'table or view' to 'SQL Command', then just wrote a select * from table name

Step 2: Went to destination and changed data access mode from 'table or view' to 'table or view - fast load'

Runs in seconds now